# Is this rose plant growing from seed?

Tags: identification, flowers, roses

I have a climbing rose next to this and I popped a bunch of seeds around the area. Is this some weed (blackberry) or rose?

It doesn’t look too happy, does it? Maybe lack of water?

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit like a sucker from an adult plant - maybe not a seedling.

Comment: Haha you are right... I just pulled it up and there was a large branch running under the loose dirt. How do you know? Maybe you can post the answer below for me to mark as Answer.

Comment: Mature leaves, and much bigger than a seedling.